# Accessing a form array with $_POST

Tags: php

I have a form with checkbox inputs and all of them have name=[ ] to create and array. Like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value= 1    
name="Todelete[]"/>

<input type="checkbox" value= 2
name="Todelete[]"/>
```

And then I send the form data with the form action attribute to a PHP script.

I use:

```
Foreach($_POST['todelete'] as $delete_id)
{
//Code to delete the rows of selected data
}
```

But for some reason I cannot get it to work. What am I doing wrong? I keep getting an error with my script.

Comment: don't start with a capital letter, like say `foreach`?

Comment: @joseph the keywords are not actually case sensitive.

Comment: clean your html: value= 1 should become value="1"

Comment: @Michael but its convention. as far as i know, you should only capitalize Class names to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst you **CAN** send arrays using plain HTML forms to PHP

Comment: I was not aware of this.

Comment: what does debugger - or var_dump($_POST); - tell you?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst better not to write inaccurate things here then ;-)

Answer (score 3):

IF this is your real code, array keys are case sensitive. Use `$_POST['Todelete']`, as in your markup you used

```
<input type="checkbox" value='2' name="Todelete[]"/>

foreach($_POST['Todelete'] as $key => $delete_id)
{
  //Code to delete the rows of selected data
}
```

Note, I have also quoted the `value` attribute.

Note also, if it is of any use to you, you can pass array keys into the HTML, which sometimes makes it easier to differentiate form inputs in an array.

```
<input type="checkbox" value='1' name="Todelete[v1]"/>
<input type="checkbox" value='2' name="Todelete[v2]"/>

// Check only for v1
if (isset($_POST['Todelete']['v1'])) {
    // v1 was sent...
}
```